# how to Run phonegap app on my windows phone 7.5

Tags: windows-phone-7, deployment, cordova

I implemented a very simple sample mobile app using phonegab.
I used Visual Studio 10 to build this app, and I have a windows phone 'htc'.

I tested the application in the vs emulator, but I want to check it on my physical phone.

Is it possible to do that without registering in the apps hub? I want to just test it, just me, will not sell it or anything.

Is that possible and how?

note: I am new in mobile dev world.

Comment: http://cisforcoder.wordpress.com/2010/10/22/unlocking-your-wp7-device-for-app-development/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to manually deploy the application is to have your phone developer unlocked. You need to buy a years membership to [Microsoft's App Hub](http://create.msdn.com) to developer unlock your phone.

So in short, **no you can't deploy without paying** for a membership.

Answer (score 2):

There is another way of unlocking a device for direct application deployment and **it's fully legal**: [ChevronWP7 Labs](http://labs.chevronwp7.com)

They suspended operations a few weeks ago because they ran out of unlocking tokens from Microsoft, but I don't know if they have more already...

Answer (score 2):

Crazy But are you student???

Check this :

https://www.dreamspark.com/

https://www.dreamspark.com/Product/Product.aspx?productid=26

http://mywpstory.com/2011/07/students-how-to-developer-unlock-jailbreak-your-windows-phone-7-device-for-free/

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the Windows phone hackers at xda-developers and install a custom ROM that enables the development for free